# Google Vision Rest API in Xamarin

Tags: rest, xamarin, dotnet-httpclient, google-cloud-vision

I'm trying to call the Google Vision REST API from a Xamarin.Forms app. I have the following code:-

```cs
 private async void SendToGoogle(MediaFile file)
    {
        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            string uri = "https://vision.googleapis.com/v1/images:annotate?key=API_KEY";
            HttpResponseMessage response;

            var stream = file.GetStream();
            using (var content = new StreamContent(stream))
            {
                content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
                content.Headers.ContentLength = stream.Length;
                response = await client.PostAsync(uri, content);

                var resp = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            }
        }
    }
```

But this is returning me a `400` error message:

> Invalid JSON payload received. Expected a value.

Comment: Not really sure what you are trying to do... Content is supposed to be Base64 encoded and you are not annotating (w/ JSON) what you expect from the content (LABEL_DETECTION, FACE_DETECTION, LANDMARKS_....). You might want to review the samples/tutorials at https://cloud.google.com/vision/

Comment: Hi, thanks, that was useful. I was struggling with the documentation but  the way you worded it made it suddenly click.